# Simple tabbed divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple task website, and I want to add the ability to create recurring tasks.

```
  <label class = "formLabel">Recurring?</label>

  <div class = "radioWrap">
    <label for="once" id = "onceLabel" class="radioLabel">One Time</label>
    <label for="repeat" id = "repeatLabel" class="radioLabel">Repeat</label>
    <input id="once" style="display: none" name="recurring" value="once" type="radio" checked>
    <input id="repeat" style="display: none" name="recurring" value="repeat" type="radio">
  </div>

  <div id = "onceD">
    <label class = "formLabel">Deadline</label>
    <input type = "date" class = "inputText" name = "dateInput" minlength = "5" maxlength = "10" placeholder = "Deadline (MM/DD/YYYY)" required>
  </div>
  <div id = "repeatD">
    <label class = "formLabel">Frequency (days)</label>
    <input type = "number" class = "inputText" name = "freqInput" min = "1" max = "20" placeholder = "Repeat every x days" required>
    <label class = "formLabel">Start date</label>
    <input type = "date" class = "inputText" name = "startInput" placeholder = "Start date (MM/DD/YYYY)" required>
    <label class = "formLabel">End date</label>
    <input type = "date" class = "inputText" name = "endInput" placeholder = "End date (MM/DD/YYYY)" required>
  </div>
```

CSS won't work due to the wrapper around the radio buttons, so how can I use pure Javascript to create a rudimentary tabbed browing experience in which a user can click on one radio button to reveal #onceD and click on the other to hide #onceD and reveal #repeatD, while disabling the hidden div's child inputs (since they are marked as required)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can't change the DOM at all, then you are right, CSS is not going to work. I suggest, though, if you can change the DOM, to do so. You have your radio buttons set to `display: none` anyway, so why not make those siblings of the content you are trying to show/hide? That way you can use just CSS for it.

### Option 1

I really hope you can change your DOM, because if you can, then using just CSS is dead simple. Check out the snippet below:

```css
#once:checked ~ #repeatD, #repeat:checked ~ #onceD {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
 <label class = "formLabel">Recurring?</label>

  <input id="once" style="display: none" name="recurring" value="once" type="radio" checked>
  <input id="repeat" style="display: none" name="recurring" value="repeat" type="radio">

  <div class = "radioWrap">
    <label for="once" id = "onceLabel" class="radioLabel">One Time</label>
    <label for="repeat" id = "repeatLabel" class="radioLabel">Repeat</label>
  </div>

  <div id = "onceD">
    <label class = "formLabel">Deadline</label>
    <input type = "date" class = "inputText" name = "dateInput" minlength = "5" maxlength = "10" placeholder = "Deadline (MM/DD/YYYY)" required>
  </div>
  <div id = "repeatD">
    <label class = "formLabel">Frequency (days)</label>
    <input type = "number" class = "inputText" name = "freqInput" min = "1" max = "20" placeholder = "Repeat every x days" required>
    <label class = "formLabel">Start date</label>
    <input type = "date" class = "inputText" name = "startInput" placeholder = "Start date (MM/DD/YYYY)" required>
    <label class = "formLabel">End date</label>
    <input type = "date" class = "inputText" name = "endInput" placeholder = "End date (MM/DD/YYYY)" required>
  </div>
```

### Option 2

Anyway, assuming you can't change the DOM one bit, you need to add a `hide` class to your CSS (which will be called by the javascript event handler to hide the appropriate tab). You then will want to see my following JavaScript code to see how I assigned event handlers to the radio buttons:

```js
// Get your radio buttons to check if they are checked
let once = document.querySelector('#once');
let repeat = document.querySelector('#repeat');
// Get your content you want to show/hide
let onceD = document.querySelector('#onceD');
let repeatD = document.querySelector('#repeatD');

// Get your inputs so you can add event listeners to them
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#once, #repeat');

// A function that will check both of your radio buttons, and take
// appropriate action based on the status of its 'checked' state
const selectActive = (e) => {
  once.checked ? onceD.classList.remove('hide') : onceD.classList.add('hide');
  repeat.checked ? repeatD.classList.remove('hide') : repeatD.classList.add('hide');
}

// Add the event listeners to the group of inputs we gathered above
// Note we are passing in the function we just defined as the handler
inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('change', selectActive));

// Since the function was externall defined (outside of the event
// handeler) we can use it to set up a default status
selectActive();
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
 <label class = "formLabel">Recurring?</label>

  <div class = "radioWrap">
    <label for="once" id = "onceLabel" class="radioLabel">One Time</label>
    <label for="repeat" id = "repeatLabel" class="radioLabel">Repeat</label>
    <input id="once" style="display: none" name="recurring" value="once" type="radio" checked>
    <input id="repeat" style="display: none" name="recurring" value="repeat" type="radio">
  </div>

  <div id = "onceD">
    <label class = "formLabel">Deadline</label>
    <input type = "date" class = "inputText" name = "dateInput" minlength = "5" maxlength = "10" placeholder = "Deadline (MM/DD/YYYY)" required>
  </div>
  <div id = "repeatD">
    <label class = "formLabel">Frequency (days)</label>
    <input type = "number" class = "inputText" name = "freqInput" min = "1" max = "20" placeholder = "Repeat every x days" required>
    <label class = "formLabel">Start date</label>
    <input type = "date" class = "inputText" name = "startInput" placeholder = "Start date (MM/DD/YYYY)" required>
    <label class = "formLabel">End date</label>
    <input type = "date" class = "inputText" name = "endInput" placeholder = "End date (MM/DD/YYYY)" required>
  </div>
```

Hopefully one of these answers is suitable for your needs. I am a personal fan of the CSS only method, since like I said you are hiding those radio buttons anyway :)

Comment: I tried the CSS-only way first, but I couldn't control the nephew(?) label styling when the corresponding radio button is checked. Is there a way around that I'm not noticing?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean - the corresponding label cascades further down the the sheet, so you should be able to target the labels with a selector such as `#once:checked #onceLabel` or something of the sort. Is that not working?

As I mentioned, the CSS only way requires the DOM to changed from the version you posted, which is why I presented 2 options - one with the DOM completely as-is, and one with a very minor alteration to it

Cheers! - Jimmy

Comment: I changed the dom to the one you suggested, but the #once:checked #onceLabel doesn't work since the label is the radio button's nephew

Comment: @JimmyVanVeen The css solution is very elegant. Didn't think of that.

Comment: @JohnS sorry, I missed some specificity in my selector. Here's one that works for me: `#once:checked ~ .radioWrap #onceLabel, #repeat:checked ~ .radioWrap #repeatLabel`. I have a codepen showing a basic change to the selected label by making the background red - check it out: https://codepen.io/JimmayVV/pen/KxpXwK

Comment: @JimmyVanVeen Thanks, I didn't know you could specify the class. Works now :)

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick using Vanilla JS. It's also dynamic in that it allows you to add more radio button/tab ids to the array at the top. Let me know if you have any questions about the code.

The main steps that make this happen are:

1. **Add Event Listeners for the change event on the radio buttons**

   `radioButton.addEventListener('change', (e) => activated(e), false);`

   This adds the event listeners to the individual radio buttons. Essentially this causes the `activated` function to be called whenever a previously unselected radio button is activated. `e` is a reference to the event being passed into the function.
2. **Hide all tabs that don't correspond to the checked radio button**

   Within the `activated` function: `currentTab.classList.add('hide');`

   This adds the css class `hide`, which sets the css property `display: none`.
3. **Show the one tab that corresponds to the checked radio button**

   Within the `activated` function: `currentTab.classList.remove('hide');`

   This removes the class, i.e. makes the tab visible again.
4. **Set your defaults appropriately**

   In the HTML: `<div id="repeatD" class="hide">` so that this div is hidden when the first page loads.
5. **Optional: Make it more generic...**

   `const tabConfiguration = ...`

   ... by storing all Ids in an array and then looping over that array instead of using static/individual Ids. Doing it generically like this avoids at least some repetition (because DRY).

```js
/* didn't include an IIFE wrapper here for brevity */

/* all ids in one place for easy-to-change and adaptable configuration
 * the tabs/toggles should are treated as mutually exclusive, i.e. no two
 * tabs are displayed at the same time */
const tabConfiguration = [{
    togglerId: 'once',
    tabId: 'onceD',
  },
  {
    togglerId: 'repeat',
    tabId: 'repeatD',
  }
]

/* loop over configuration and
 * add an event listener to each radio button that fires when the button is checked */
for (let i = 0; i < tabConfiguration.length; i += 1) {
  const radioButton = document.getElementById(tabConfiguration[i].togglerId);
  /* add event listeners that fire when the radio button is checked */
  radioButton.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    activated(e)
  }, false);
}

/* event listener function called by each event listener when an event is fired */
function activated(e) {
  /* match against the id*/
  for (let i = 0; i < tabConfiguration.length; i += 1) {
    const currentTab = document.getElementById(tabConfiguration[i].tabId);
    console.log(currentTab.id);
    if (e.target.id === tabConfiguration[i].togglerId) {
      /* if it matches show it, i.e. remove the hide class */
      currentTab.classList.remove('hide');
    } else {
      /* all other ones should be hidden (as mentioned tabs are mutually exclusive) */
      currentTab.classList.add('hide');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label class="formLabel">Recurring?</label>

<div class="radioWrap">
  <label for="once" id="onceLabel" class="radioLabel">One Time</label>
  <input id="once" name="recurring" value="once" type="radio" checked>
  <label for="repeat" id="repeatLabel" class="radioLabel">Repeat</label>
  <input id="repeat" name="recurring" value="repeat" type="radio">
</div>

<div id="onceD">
  <label class="formLabel">Deadline</label>
  <input type="date" class="inputText" name="dateInput" minlength="5" maxlength="10" placeholder="Deadline (MM/DD/YYYY)" required>
</div>
<div id="repeatD" class="hide">
  <label class="formLabel">Frequency (days)</label>
  <input type="number" class="inputText" name="freqInput" min="1" max="20" placeholder="Repeat every x days" required>
  <label class="formLabel">Start date</label>
  <input type="date" class="inputText" name="startInput" placeholder="Start date (MM/DD/YYYY)" required>
  <label class="formLabel">End date</label>
  <input type="date" class="inputText" name="endInput" placeholder="End date (MM/DD/YYYY)" required>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this to get the radio buttons working.

html

```
<input id="swap1" type="radio"  name="rad" value="onceD" onclick="">OnceD</input>
<input id="swap2" type="radio" name="rad" value="repeatD"  onclick="">repeatD</input>


<input id="testButton" type="button" onclick="swap();">Test</input>


<div id = "onceD">
<label class = "formLabel">Deadline</label>
<input type = "date" class = "inputText" name = "dateInput" minlength = "5" maxlength = "10" placeholder = "Deadline (MM/DD/YYYY)" required>
</div>
<div id = "repeatD">
<label class = "formLabel">Frequency (days)</label>
<input type = "number" class = "inputText" name = "freqInput" min = "1" max = "20" placeholder = "Repeat every x days" required>
<label class = "formLabel">Start date</label>
<input type = "date" class = "inputText" name = "startInput" placeholder = "Start date (MM/DD/YYYY)" required>
<label class = "formLabel">End date</label>
<input type = "date" class = "inputText" name = "endInput" placeholder = "End date (MM/DD/YYYY)" required>
</div>
```

javascript

```
var x=document.getElementById("swap1");
var y=document.getElementById("swap2");
var onceD = document.getElementById("onceD");
var repeatD = document.getElementById("repeatD");


function swap()
{

if(x.checked == true)
 {
  onceD.style.display = 'block';
  repeatD.style.display = 'none';
 }

if(y.checked == true)
 {
  onceD.style.display = 'none';
  repeatD.style.display = 'block';
 }

}
```

Unfortunately, there was an issue getting the radio buttons to update the divs with ONLY radio buttons. So I added a button to check which radio button is checked. I would have shared the JSFiddle, but it didn't work there.

You might be able to get it working with just the radio buttons, but I think you need to use jQuery.

It also would be possible and possibly easier to do this using other input types.

Comment: Are you dead set on using radio buttons?

Comment: Not at all dead set. I just used them as a starting point since the website has a few other buttons with a similar structure and styling